# Execute two roles and also Can we add two recipes in runlist?

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook

I have created a role myrole inside that i added two receipes under run list

```
"run_list" : [

"recipe[sala::default],[sala::test]"

]
```

But it is giving me error.

So later i want to do

```
knife bootstarp ipaddress -x user -i key --sudo - r role[myrole]
```

When I run the above command i want to my chef run to execute both the receipes on single run.

Also, can i execute this command with two roles?

```
knife bootstarp ipaddress -x user -i key --sudo - r role[myrole1,myrole2]
```

Comment: In order to improve the quality of your questions, please make sure to included details instead of "But it is giving me error."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, except typos (`bootstarp` -> `bootstrap`) and tiny glitches (`- r` -> `-r`) your only problem is that you have to prepend the `[sala::test]` with a `recipe`:

```
run_list" : [
  "recipe[sala::default],recipe[sala::test]"
]
```

Similar, when bootstrapping, do it like this: `-r "role[myrole1],role[myrole2]"`

EDIT: the json example was incorrect. This should work:

```
run_list" : [
  "recipe[sala::default]",
  "recipe[sala::test]"
]
```

Comment: when i do this"recipe[sala::default],recipe[sala::test]" im getting this error: ArgumentError: Unable to create Chef::RunList::RunListItem from String:"recipe[sala::default],recipe[sala::test]": must be recipe[] or role[]
@StephenKing

Comment: bootstapping using two role can be done @Stephenking but error in runlist when i use two recipes